# How do you parse 150g csv file using Elixir? Shell? SQL database?

Tags: python, sql-server, shell, csv, elixir

The problem - I have 150GB csv file with headers and the same number of columns for each row. I need just the first column, minus the headers, and only the unique items. The csv cannot be on my local machine since I do not have the space. It is on an apple Airport. I will try and connect with a usb cable.

I have been scouring the internet for a solution for about 3 days now. I have heard a couple of solutions but am not sure which is the best approach. Which one is best and why?

- Shell: I hear I can do this with shell but I have no shell writing experience in this realm
- Python script: I did create a script but gave up after it was running for 4 hours. This might be because I was accessing it over wifi.
- Elixir: I am currently learning elixir and have been told Flow would be a good choice to partition out my work over my cpu's while I read in new information. Comparing Stream with Flow. on 1 million list of similar data it took 8 seconds with Stream and 2 seconds with Flow to get all unique items in the file.

  `def stream_parse(file_path, chunk_size) do
    file_path
      |> File.stream!
      |> Stream.drop(1)
      |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1, ",") |> List.first)
      |> Stream.chunk(chunk_size, chunk_size, [])
      |> Stream.map(&MapSet.new(&1))
      |> Enum.to_list
  end`

  `def flow_parse(file_path, chunk_size) do
    file_path
      |> File.stream!(read_ahead: chunk_size)
      |> Stream.drop(1)
      |> Flow.from_enumerable
      |> Flow.map(&String.split(&1, ",") |> List.first)
      |> Flow.partition
      |> Flow.uniq
      |> Enum.to_list
  end`

The I do not particularly have an issue with the stream solution although
it has high memory usage, uses 1 thread, and is ran on one core. 
The flow solution is multithreaded, uses multiple cores, but has the issue of creating everything finally into one `Enum.to_list` that could end up being who knows how long

- SQL Server: Lastly I was told just to create a linux server and have SQL and load the data into sql and run a query to get the data.

What is the best approach and if so is there an even better solution. Besides writing C.

### Edit 1 12/6/2017 . d/m/y

I was able to finish the stream and flow examples with elixir. I was also given a shell script that accomplishes the needed results. So far the shell script and the stream operate at the same speed with flow winning. However since it is not local to my machine flow will make no difference because I am IO bound.

```
def stream_parse(file_path, chunk_size, output_file) do
  file_path
    |> File.stream!(read_ahead: chunk_size)
    |> Stream.drop(1)
    |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1, ",") |> List.first)
    |> Stream.uniq
    |> Stream.map(&"#{&1}\n")
    |> Stream.into(File.stream!(output_file, [:write, :utf8]))
    |> Stream.run
end
```

However this lacks the ability to write a file of results for each chunk and will store the unique items for the entire 150g in memory(not an option).

The shell script(Also stores all unique items in memory)

```
tail -n +2 my.csv | cut -d , -f 1 | sort -u > OUTPUT.csv
```

Comment: I'd pipe the data from the remote server into a local script. For Elixir, https://github.com/plataformatec/nimble_csv should be able to handle streaming data from STDIN just fine with low memory usage. You might not need to complicate things with Flow if I/O is the bottleneck.

Comment: How many records you have inside this file? As for unique items - is the file sorted somehow and unique files are always grouped together?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how was this monster created and what made the creator think if was a good choice?

Comment: show the first 10 lines with command `head yourfilename`

Comment: @Dogbert I added my two elixir solutions. But am lost on how to avoid creating a `Enum.list` with all the unique items in the Flow solution. @ Artur R. Czechowski I cannot open the file. It is too large for any program to open. They could be sorted together but am not 100%. @Klaus D. pulled from an sql database. No access. @RomanPerekhrest Why would seeing the first 10 lines make anything easier? It is a csv, header, each row has the same # of columns. I only need the first column. The data in the rest of the columns is not needed.

Comment: Do you realise, that keeping unique values for this monster requires probably some kind of persistency while sorting, as 150GB of data won't fit into RAM?

Comment: @enedil exactly. I do not have the code in the elixir scripts to write the unique items to a new file yet. And this is why it is a question. How would this be accomplished.

Comment: To make it easier, I would create a new file that contains first column only. In bash `tail -n +2 big_file.csv | awk '{print $1} > a_little_smaller_file.csv`. What is the resulting size?

Comment: @enedil I will have to run it on Monday when I have access again.

Comment: forgot to mention - if your csv is delimited by someting other than whitespace, you'd better replace this awk command with `cut -d"," -f1` - here comma as an example

Answer (score 3):

While finally searching many forums, the elixir slack channel. We finally came up with a solution. First was to split the file up since there is already a shell command for this, there is no need to over complicate the elixir code. I broke everything up into methods to better explain what is all going on.

Break file up into 10 million line sub files

```
$ mkdir split-files 
$ split -a 8 -l 10000000 big_file.csv ./split-files
$ cd split-files 
$ for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.csv"; done
```

Next we needed to get the unique items from each file, and write a unique file for the output. I am able to actually use Flow.uniq since the chunk_size will be 10 million which can fit into memory.

```
def flow_parse_dir(path, chunk_size) do
  Path.wildcard(path <> "/*.csv")
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map(fn filename ->
        [dir, file] = String.split(filename,"/")
        flow_parse(filename, chunk_size, dir <> "/unique_"<> file)
      end)
    |> Flow.run
end
def flow_parse(file_path, chunk_size, output_file) do
  file_path
    |> File.stream!(read_ahead: chunk_size)
    |> Stream.drop(1)
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map(&String.split(&1, ",") |> List.first)
    |> Flow.partition
    |> Flow.uniq
    |> Flow.map(&"#{&1}\n")
    |> Stream.into(File.stream!(output_file, [:write, :utf8]))
    |> Stream.run
end
```

After all the unique files were created we need to create a total unique file.

```
def concat_files(path, totol_unique_file_name) do
  sum_file =  File.open!(path <> "/" <> totol_unique_file_name, [:read, :utf8, :write])

  Path.wildcard(path <> "/*.csv")
    |> Stream.map(fn filename ->
        [_, file] = String.split(filename, "/")
        if String.contains?(file, "unique") do
          write_concat_of_unique_files(file, path, sum_file)
        end
      end)
    |> Stream.run

  File.close(sum_file)
end
def write_concat_of_unique_files(file, path, totol_unique_file_name) do
  # read in file contents line by line
  path <> "/" <> file
    |> File.stream!()
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim(&1,"\n"))
    |> Stream.map(fn line ->
        IO.puts(totol_unique_file_name, line)
      end)
    |> Stream.run
end
```

Finally a method at the end that should finish the job.

```
def unique_column(file_path, chunk_size, output) do
  total_file = File.open!(output, [:read, :utf8, :write])

  file_path
    |> File.stream!(read_ahead: chunk_size)
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim(&1,"\n"))
    |> Stream.chunk(chunk_size, chunk_size, [])
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map(fn chunk ->
        chunk
          |> MapSet.new
          |> MapSet.to_list
          |> List.flatten
      end)
    |> Flow.partition
    |> Flow.map(fn line ->
        Enum.map(line, fn item ->
            IO.puts(total_file, item)
          end)
        end)
    |> Flow.run

  File.close(total_file)
end
```

Check if final file is completely unique. The number of unique items from previous files was realized to not be too large and fit completely into memory. If the contents are all unique then you will get the list as a return. If you get an error it was not unique.

```
def check_unique(file_path) do
  original_length = file_path
    |> File.stream!
    |> Enum.to_list

  unique_length = file_path
    |> File.stream!
    |> Stream.uniq
    |> Enum.to_list

  ^unique_length = original_length
end
```